# Element stays hidden using jquery .hide() before .animate()

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

I'm trying to place a hidden validation popup on the DOM, and then animate it in when the form is sent. I have found that the jQuery animation methods operate differently when using either `.hide()` or `.css(opacity, 0)` prior to animating the element into full opacity.

Early in the code, if I use `.hide()`, `.animate()` with its opacity property set to 1, will not work at all. However, the .fadeIn() method works just using `.hide()` first. If I set the element's `opacity` to 0 with the `.css()` method, then `.animation()` will fade in the element. I would like to use `.animate()` because of the flexibility and added options.

I had decided to just go ahead and use the `.css()` approach, but then ran into a problem with trying to support IE8. `.css(opacity, 0)` will not hide the element in IE8, so my only option at this point is to use `.fadeIn()` for what I'm trying to accomplish.

Has anyone else ran into this issue, and if so, could I bum some advice from you =)

Answer (score 0):

the `hide` and 'fadeIn/fadeOut`methods toggle the`display:`css property. Whereas animating the opactiy, does not. I've found the simplest fix for this is to call`fadeTo` instead of hide and just fade to 0 opacity.

```
$('#target-element').fadeTo( 0, 0 ).fadeTo( 3000, 1 );
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a case where it's really helpful to read the source code of jQuery. `hide()` actually sets a `display:none` declaration on the CSS. Once `display:none` is set, that element is hidden even if you change the opacity.

If you want that element to be visible again, you first need to set `display:block`. This is exactly what `fadeIn()` does: it first calls `show()` (which sets `display:block`), then animates opacity.

So, your options are either to do this display toggling yourself while manually running opacity animations, or simply use the fadeIn/Out helper methods.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem before as well. I found this explanation for the behaviour of hide, fade and animate.

http://www.catchmyfame.com/2010/08/31/jquery-hide-vs-fadeout-vs-animate/

I think jquery does a lot of browser-specific mumbo jumbo with animate opacity to hide the misgivings of ie. What you could do is have a class that keeps your element offscreen, applied in the html, then use query to animate it invisible, remove the off-screen holder class and then animate it in when you need it.

I use a class with position:absolute and left:100% for some of my stuff. Seems to work.